# Реализация превью чужого окна

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Как реализовать превью чужих окон в своём окне? Аналогично нажатию alt+tab
[image: Зажатый alt+tab]

Снятие скриншота и вывод в PictureBox очень нагружает комьютер (в отличии от alt+tab)

Comment: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx

Comment: То что нужно, но после сворачивания изображение "замирает", а после перемещения окна из которого идёт превью оно просто пропадает.